I need a nut-free substitution for Heath bars
Because of a severe nut allergy, I need a substitution for Heath bars bits in a recipe. The recipe is a chocolate trifle which includes chocolate cake, chocolate pudding, Cool Whip and milk mixed with Kahlua.

What specific nuts is the person you're cooking for allergic to? Maybe you can simply substitute a nut that is safe.

"Severe nut allergy" generally means "avoid all nuts, and peanuts, too, just to be safe from cross-contamination".

wait you're just chopping heath bars and adding it to the recipe? How about just not adding it?

Heath bars are nuts, hard toffee,
and chocolate.
I would break up come sort of toffee or butterscotch candy, and add some chocolate bits (chunks, chips, maybe shavings if it's the last thing on top)
You might not need the chocolate, with the cake and pudding
